# Removing the .php file extension from the URL Request

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to beautify my URLs and want to get rid of the .php file extension. I've found a couple of other questions here such as this one ([Removing the PHP file type extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41019584/removing-the-php-file-type-extension)) But none of the suggestions work for me. They send me to my 404.php or do not change the URL at all.

I figure the entire RewriteEngine code in my htaccess as a whole is conflicting in itself.

Here's what I got so far,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]


    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [R]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /404.php [R]
</IfModule>
```

I would like my domains to look like

> https://www.example.com/about

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `Redirect`, `RedirectMatch` and `RewriteRule` directives in same .htaccess as they come from different Apache modules and their load sequence is unpredictable.

Have it this way:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing this change.

Comment: I'll be back in about an hour. This covers the file extension removal and 404?

Comment: Worked like a charm with minimal amount of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

#1)externally redirect "/file.php" to "/file"
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

#2)Internally map "/file" back to "/file.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,L]

ErrorDocument 404 ./404
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^404/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./404 [L]

Redirect 301 /index /
```

Comment: Didn't work. I got sent to my 404 and a message that says it redirected too many times. Keep in mind, I have my htaccess setup to send pages not matching my REQUEST_FILENAME to my 404.php

Comment: I have updated the answer. Also try to restart the webserver

Comment: Now we're unto something! Loving it so far! Except one minor detail. I had it so that the index.php showed a /...Now it shows example.com/index. How can I specifically omit the index from the main page?

Comment: I would be fine with either version `www.example.com/` or `www.example.com`

Comment: add RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: `The requested URL / was not found on this server.` On the home page, and 500 error on all other pages now

Comment: Oh man you're so close, yet so far lol No errors, except going to the home page send me to a 404 instead

Comment: I'll get back to this in an hour.

Answer (score 0):

remove .php from the link :

```
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: It didn't remove the .php

Comment: @LOTUSMS i update my code , it's exactly what i am using in my htaccess

Comment: It's probably a different configuration in your site. Your update breaks the connection between my paths and the stylesheets and JS files are not accessed. Plus every page is going to 404. My guess is I'd have to manually remove the .php from the HTML `<a>` tags too but that's not ideal. Thanks anyway